# discord.js: how can i make an exception for pinging staff?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

Recently I was working on an anti-ping staff feature.

Code:

```js
const ownerId = "368033271029956609";
    
    client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;
    
    if (message.mentions.has(ownerId)) {
        await message.delete();
        message.reply(`please, do not ping/tag this person!`).then(msg => 
        { msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })});
     }
});
```

But today I noticed that if I ping @everyone in #announcements, it notices that I pinged staff. So, how can I make an exception for a specific channel? What do I have to add to this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for a staff mention **and** if the mention was not made in the announcement channel by checking channel id's.

```
const ownerId = "368033271029956609";
const channelId = "announcement-channel-id-here";

    client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.mentions.has(ownerId) && message.channel.id !== channelId) {
        await message.delete();
        message.reply(`please, do not ping/tag this person!`).then(msg => 
        { msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })});
     }
});
```

Comment: it kind of doesnt work, first of all, message and channel should be united with ., i fixed that and it still doesnt work

Comment: Edited, can you provide debugging details?

Comment: can you provide your discord pls

Comment: No. The discussion will remain here

Comment: it keeps blocking pinging staff and sends in console this:

`(node:369) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/aftbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/aftbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async MessageManager.delete (/home/runner/aftbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/MessageManager.js:126:5) ` (cut bcuz it is too big)

Comment: Have you provided the right id for the announcement channel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231248/discussion-between-papacito-and-elitezen).

Comment: i am sorry, i had another script that deletes it